# How do I fix this error on replit, I am trying to make a discord bot but this error keeps showing up

Tags: python, discord

This is the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7TNL.png

I have tried importing os `import os` but it won't stop giving this error
This is is the code

````
import os
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.bot(command_prefix="!")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))


#say command
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, say: str):
    await ctx.send(say)


bot.run('no peeks')```
````

Comment: Please share all code and errors as text.

Comment: Also, don't share your API key. You'll have to create another one.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```py
bot = commands.bot(command_prefix="!")
```

with

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
```

Comment: Thank you it has been fixed

Comment: @Keith Glad to help! If my answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the big checkmark to select it as the accepted answer, so people answering can focus on older questions which still don't have answers.